# Magento 1.9 multiple pricerules pick the highest discount

Tags: rules

At our magento site we have some different price rules where some of the products affected are the same. 
But it should not apply all rules to the product only one, we want it to set the discount bythe rule that gives the highest discount. All rules are set to give a percentage discount.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Two Way to Set Discount in Magento

1,Catalog Price Rule

2,Cart Price Rule(Like COUPON)

What use to set your Discount Rule?

Comment: We use catalog price rule

Comment: Catalog Price Rule is use to make the Discount for Specific Category of product with the set of Rules.



What Rule you apply for Discount?

Comment: We have added a bunch of products to a category(all products where there is 2 in stock and whioch haven't been sold since 2017) and then we have set a Catalog Price Rule on that category. But the products in the category, is also in other categories which have assigned catalog price rules to them

Comment: You need to apply the discount Rule for not-sold product(in-stock) in 2017

,my understanding is correct or Not?

Comment: We have created a category and applied a dynamic rule to that category that says take all where stock is minimum 2 AND last sold is less than 2017.

Comment: And it is to that categry that we have applied a category price rule